# how to syncronize retrofit in viewmodel?

Tags: android, android-mvvm

I'm studying mvvm. When I call init(), the first call is null.
using retrofit, I think the reason is that the function `getIndexRetrofit()` is returned before the line execute `data.value = res`. So I wanna syncronize this, expecting the function to return not null but the response values.  when I click button, the value 'binding.user!!.login' is null.

**Repository:**

```
fun getIndexRetrofit(name:String) : MutableLiveData<UserModel>{   

    Retrofit2Service.getService().requestUserInfo(name).enqueue(object: Callback<UserModel> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserModel>, t: Throwable) {
           data.postValue(null)
        }
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserModel>, response: Response<UserModel>) {
            if(response.body()!=null) {
                var res = response.body()!!

                data.value = res
            }
        }
    })//Retrofit

    return data
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
    lateinit var mIndexModel : MutableLiveData<UserModel>
    lateinit var mRepository : MainRepository

    fun init(name:String){
        mRepository =  MainRepository().getInstance()
        mIndexModel = mRepository.getIndexRetrofit(name)
        //Log.d("TAG",mIndexModel.value.toString())
    }

    fun getIndexList(): MutableLiveData<UserModel> {
        return mIndexModel
    }
```

**OnCreate:**

```
 mainViewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        mainViewModel.init("ckdrb7017")
        mainViewModel.getIndexList().observe(this, Observer<UserModel>(){
                t->
            if(t==null){
                Log.d("TAG","NULL");
            }else{
                Log.d("TAG","SUCCESS");
                binding.user=t
            }

        })

        binding.url.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            var intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("userId", binding.user!!.login)
            startActivity(intent)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `binding.executePendingBindings()` after assign user

```
binding.user=t
binding.executePendingBindings()
```

But good practice is to use another variable in your `Activity/Fragment` to hold `UserModel` and use that variable in your `intent`

```
private userModel: UserModel? = null
...

userModel = t
binding.user=t
binding.executePendingBindings()
```

and then

```
var intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("userId", userModel?.login)
startActivity(intent)
```